# android findviewbyid() issues

Tags: android, xml

I have the following code and i am trying to retrieve an id from the main.xml however netbeans is showing an error that id variable not found .I cant see what im doing wrong heres the code anyway

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

     <TextView
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="45px"
    android:text="Helllo mw "
    android:textColor="@color/aqua"
    android:id="@+id/my_id2"
    />



</LinearLayout>
```

I am trying to retrieve the id my_id2 in the code heres the code

```
package bomb.com;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

Button sup;
TextView uno;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    uno=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_id2);
}

}
```

thanks ..

Comment: looks OK, try clean rebuild, maybe net beans got a regenerate R file action?

Comment: If deceiver's answer helped, please remember to upvote and mark as accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So it seems correct, try to *clean and rebuild* your project again and restart `NetBeans`.

Comment: I just restarted netbeans and cleaned the project and it has worked thanks .

Answer (score 1):

- "Clean" your project.
- if that doesn't solve it, make sure you are including the correct xml file in `setContentView()`

Answer (score 1):

If its showing error on line

```
uno=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_id2);
```

than import R(with package name in which class is saved).

Comment: Thanks for all the answers i restarted netbeans and cleaned the project and it had no errors.

Answer (score 0):

try to make project clean and then check id values again  and save xml file